# How to detect change in model for multidimensional array in angular js

Tags: angularjs, multidimensional-array, angularjs-scope

I want to fire an event when my multidimensional scope variable get changed i.e. element added, removed etc. I tried to do so using $scope.$watch and $scope.$watchCollection, but its not working.

This is the scenario.

```
$scope.variable=[{ID:1,text:'abc'},{ID:1,text:'abc'}];
$scope.content='';

$scope.$watch('$scope.variable',function(){
$scope.content=$scope.variable[0].text;
});
```

Any help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `true` as an argument

```
$scope.$watch('variable',function(){
   $scope.content=$scope.variable[0].text;
}, true);
```

NB: no need for `$scope` in argument